# JPA retorno ordenado do lado Many de uma entidade @OneToMany usando @OrderBy

Tags: jsf, hibernate, jpa

Tenho a seguinte entidade `Cliente` que possui `Pedidos`.

A relação entre clientes e pedidos está mapeada com `Cliente @OneToMany` e `Pedidos @ManyToOne`. O que preciso é que a lista de Pedidos dos Clientes venha ordenada por `Pedido.id`.

Após algumas pesquisas descobri que devo usar `@OrderBy`, o problema é que não estou sabendo utilizá-lo. Segue o código:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Cliente implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Email
    @NotEmpty
    private String email;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy ="cliente",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OrderBy("cliente.Pedido.id ASC")
    private List<Pedido> pedidos;


@Entity
@Table
public class Pedido implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_pedido")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Cliente cliente;
```

Visto isso, como deve ser minha anotação `@OrderBy` para que quando eu puxe os clientes, os pedidos venham ordenados por `id`?

Segue o código de como faço a consulta dos dados:

```
public class ClientePU implements Serializable{
    @Inject
    private EntityManager manager;

    public Cliente clientePorEmail(String email){
        return manager.find(Cliente.class, email);
    }

    public void salvarNovoCliente(Cliente cliente){
        manager.merge(cliente);
    }
}
```

Ao consultar clientes, o framework já me retorna a lista de Cliente com os devidos joins em Pedidos...

Comment: Como está consultando estes registros? Está usando Criteria, JPQL? Não sou fã de usar o `@OrderBy` para tratar problemas que podem ser específicos.

Comment: Estou utilizando EntityManager public class ClientePU implements Serializable{
 @Inject
 private EntityManager manager;
 
 public Cliente clientePorEmail(String email){
  return manager.find(Cliente.class, email);
 }

Comment: edite sua pergunta e coloque o código acima lá na pergunta :). Fica mais legível desta maneira e esta parte é muito importante na sua pergunta

Comment: Segue o codigo editado acima

Comment: @MuriloMedeiros a solução deve estar **sempre** na área das respostas. Visto que já há uma resposta que resolve o problema, você não precisa fazer mais nada - só o fato de ter aceitado a resposta já indica que ela solucionou seu problema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se eu fosse você, abriria mão do `@OrderBy`, pois ele seria aplicado nos pedidos para qualquer consulta da entidade Cliente. Eu recomendo usar JPQL para fazer esta consulta:

```
public Cliente clientePorEmail(String email) {
    Query query = manager.createQuery("SELECT cliente FROM Cliente cliente
        JOIN cliente.pedidos pedido 
        WHERE cliente.email = :email ORDER BY pedido.id");
    query.setParameter("email", email);
    return (Cliente) query.getSingleResult();
}
```

Se realmente deseja usar a anotação, você pode usar ele da seguinte forma se o objetivo é ordernar pelo ID de pedidos:

```
@OrderBy("id ASC")
List <Pedido> pedidos;
```

Comment: Perdao pela resposta anterior, tinha lido o codigo de outra forma... Eu nao tenho a intenção de utilizar Query desse modo pois vai resultar na performance da aplicação... Utilizar @OrderBy seria uma ótima opção para mim!

Comment: @MuriloMedeiros, qual paradigma está quebrando? Mas veja minha resposta novamente, coloquei como usar a anotação OrderBy.

Comment: Boa ! resolvido! Como faço pra marcar o topico como resolvido?

Comment: @MuriloMedeiros, só aceitar a resposta (como já fez) que no SOpt isto já significa que foi resolvido.